# Legality of commercial music in a free game

Tags: dmca

I am currently in development of a free mobile game (no ads). It is a music mixing game. Are there any legal actions I would need to take to use commercial music in my game? Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pay royalties for any music that is under copyright (i.e. most music). The peak recording body in you country usually has a scheme which allows this to be done efficiently.

Comment: I'm in the U.S. I understand about royalties however are there no loop holes on the matter regarding utilizing music in free games. Possibly a time limit of the music, not an entire track? I remember a while back hearing how it is legal to give away free cds of music with the label "For Promotional Use Only" and would see many cds with this label in my neighborhood.

Comment: @Jesse the people giving away promotional cds are generally the copyright holders or licensees.  Of course it is legal to give away something you own.  I think you're looking for the "fair use" exception to copyright protection, but that is highly unlikely to apply to the situation you describe unless the time limit is very short indeed.

Comment: @phoog 4 bars of music springs to mind in Australian case law - about 5-8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to contact owner of the music rights and then use it with his consent.